# Logstash Grok Filter

Tags: firewall, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I'm new to working Logstash.
The filter I'm trying to apply is for some firewall logs and I have a field that will either have a single or two values separated by a colon.

X16-V523
X16-V523:example.com

I have been using for the line with two values,

%{GREEDYDATA:srcint}:%{GREEDYDATA:srchost}

How do i make the second part of the match optional?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

`(%{GREEDYDATA:srcint}:%{GREEDYDATA:srchost})|(%{GREEDYDATA:srcint})`

also test with http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/